# How to set background-color on every page in wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: javascript, css, wkhtmltopdf

Here's the generated [pdf of wkhtmltopdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ7F1.png) the second page doesn't have a background color and border. I want to apply background-color and border for every page using laravel blade and wkhtmltopdf.

Here's the body and footer CSS:

```css
body {
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #e8e8e8 !important;
  width: 99.2%;
  height: 759px !important;
  height: auto;
  border-top: 6px solid #383434;
  border-left: 6px solid #383434;
  border-right: 6px solid #383434;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.content {
  width: 306px !important;
  min-height: 350px;
  /* height: 753px !important; */
  background-color: #474747;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: -webkit-box; /* wkhtmltopdf uses this one */
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
.top-section {
  background-color: #383434;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100.1%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.bottom-section {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box; /* wkhtmltopdf uses this one */
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center; /* wkhtmltopdf uses this one */
  justify-content: center;
  height: 175px;
}
```

Here's the body laravel blade:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
      family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Proof of Order</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- content -->
<div class="container">
    <table class="ct-table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="left-content">
                    <p>Product(s): 1,2,3,4</p>
                    <h>Material Type:</h>
                    <div class="type">
                        <div class="box"></div>
                        <div><p>Windows Graphics</p></div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Dimensions:</p>
                    <ul class="dimensions">
                        <li>1 - W: 49.5"| H: 54.25"</li>
                        <li>2 - W: 49.5"| H: 54.25"</li>
                        <li>3 - W: 49.5"| H: 35.25"</li>
                        <li>4 - W: 49.5"| H: 35.25"</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Options:</p>
                    <!--Addition of option list in table layout-->
                            <table class="option-list" id="option-list">
                                <tr>
                                  <td> <img src="price_point.svg" alt="" 
                                  class="option-logo"></td>
                                  <td> <p>Price Point 2/$4.00</p></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                  
                            <table class="option-list">
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <img src="comments.svg" alt="" 
                                     class="option-logo"></td>
                                    <td> <p>Comments/Text: "Thanks for Shopping"</p> 
                                   </td>
                                </tr>  
                            </table>                           
                     
                            <table class="option-list">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="logo.svg" alt="" class="option- 
                                      logo"></td>
                                    <td><p>Logo: logo.png</p></td>
                                </tr>  
                            </table>     
                     
                    </ul>
                       <!--Addition of quanity count in table layout-->
                    <table class="quantity-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Quantity: 2</p></td>
                            <td> <img src="qty.svg" alt=""  class="option-logo"></td>
                        </tr>  
                    </table>    
                </div>
                <div class="right-content">
                    <img src="me_1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
             </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the php code:

```
        $footerHtml = view()->make('admin.reports.final_proof.footer', compact('data'))- 
        >render();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.reports.final_proof.pdf', compact('data', 'products', 
        'no_of_products'))
        ->setOptions(array(
                'page-size' => 'A4',
                'margin-top' => 0,
                'margin-right' => 0,
                'margin-left' => 0,
                'margin-bottom' => 48,
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'footer-html' => $footerHtml,
                'enable-javascript' => true,
                'page-width'=>'279.5',
                'page-height'=>'216.0'
        ));
```

Here's the footer laravel blade:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Proof of Order</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
    var pdfInfo = {};
    var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var i in x) {
        var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
        pdfInfo[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
    }

    function getPdfInfo() {
        var page = pdfInfo.page || 1;
        var pageCount = pdfInfo.topage || 1;
        document.getElementById('pdfkit_page_current').textContent = page;
        document.getElementById('pdfkit_page_count').textContent = pageCount;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:getPdfInfo()" style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;">
    <div class="footer">
                <div class="top-section">
        <p>ORDER# MEC_EO-150454_AbingstonStopNGas</p>
        <p>PAGE 1 OF 1</p>
        <p>Designer: Ryan Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-section">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="monster_energy.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="order">
             <!--Changing into table layout since flex/grid feature doesn't work-->
            <table class="option-list" id="option-list">
                <tr>
                  <td> <div class="order-type">
                    <img src="man.png" alt="">
                    <p>Ordered By</p>
                </div></td>
                  <td> <div class="text-content">
                    <p>Johnboy VanSampson</p>
                    <p>johnboy@cocacola.com</p>
                    <p>720-555-5698</p>
                </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="location">
              <!--Changing into table layout since flex/grid feature doesn't work-->
            <table class="option-list" id="option-list">
                <tr>
                  <td> <div  class="order-type">
                    <img src="shop.png" alt="">
                    <p>Project <br> Location</p>
                </div></td>
                  <td>  <div class="text-content">
                    <p>Abington Stop N Gas</p>
                    <p>Attn:Johnboy VanSampson</p>
                    <p>1562 Hiltop Pallace Blvd.</p>
                    <p>Swingtown, NJ 77895</p>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </div>
        <div class="shipping">
              <!--Changing into table layout since flex/grid feature doesn't work-->
            <table class="option-list" id="option-list">
                <tr>
                  <td> <div class="order-type">
                    <img src="car.png" alt="">
                    <p>Shipping</p>
                </div></td>
                  <td> <div class="text-content">
                    <p>Abington Stop N Gas</p>
                    <p>Attn:Johnboy VanSampson</p>
                    <p>1562 Hiltop Pallace Blvd.</p>
                    <p>Swingtown, NJ 77895</p>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>     
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```